# How to use IF with Button in java Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, android-intent

i want to make button that move into new activity but in some condition. if i used button1 then show data about A, and if used button2 the show data about B.

i tried intent to new activity for each button but i have to make new class right? so thats why i just want used IF like i said before

```
Button move_found = findViewById(R.id.btn_found);
Button move_conc = findViewById(R.id.btn_conc);

move_found.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
move_conc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

thats my code for each Button, how to put IF for each button? i must put the IF code in here (MakeupMenu.class) , or in a new activity named MakeActivity.class?

Comment: you don't need `if`. You created different click listeners for each button, therefore clicking button1 will trigger it's click lisetner. Instead set different activity classes in ddifferent click listeners

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko actually i want each button move to same activity, but show different data. thats why i need 'IF' to each button. but thank you for helping:)

Comment: you don't need `if` even this way. You can put some parameter to the intent to show which button was clicked, and pass it to next activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use the method of passing data through an intent. This will allow the MakeActivity to receive data from either buttons and decides which view to show.

Use the following code for your buttons

```
move_found.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeupActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data,"button1");
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    });


move_conc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeupActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("data","button2");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Then in your MakeupActivity, receive the data and choose what to show with it. Create 2 separate layouts in your res/layout folder. Lets call them layout1.xml and layout2.xml .\
layout1.xml is for the view after button 1 is clicked and layout2.xml is for the view of the other button. Now in your MakeupActivity.class, write the following code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");


    if (data.equals("button1")){
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
    }
    if (value.equals("button2")){
        setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` is completely unnecessary here. You're setting the same intent for both button click listeners.

```
Button move_found = findViewById(R.id.btn_found);
Button move_conc = findViewById(R.id.btn_conc);

move_found.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeupActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
move_conc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //This intent also takes you to MakeupActivity
                //Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeupActivity.class);

                //Instead, you probably want to point to a different activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MakeupMenu.this, MakeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

P.S - Learn about the basic language constructs of Java, and then learn android using some guided material(any good android book or [site](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/android-training/)).

Comment: i want to each button move to same activity but show different data. thats why i need `if` for each button. but i got the answer already. thankyou at least for helping me